# What changes were done in a form using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, field, nested-attributes

Regarding this article: [tracking activerecord objects](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects)

I need to know what fields are changed in a big form using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Currently the form works well as expected. But in addition I'm doing a "log history" about user's changes.

I have tried the hash mapping, but is really complicated to me since the models aren't small, and talking about the above article maybe exists a better way to track changes.

My models are (in case is necessary):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :addresses

  attr_accessible :nom, :prenom, :langue, :nationalite, :codeFiscal, :hidden_status, :subscribed
  attr_accessible :addresses_attributes, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many   :telephones

  attr_accessible :flag, :societe, :titre, :persContact, :rue, :rue1, :nopostal, :lieu, :pays
  attr_accessible :hidden_status
  attr_accessible :telephones_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :telephones, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address

  attr_accessible :typeNumero, :numeroTel
end
```

(models are very normal).

Any ideas?, and if I'm forced to map the hash, have you a little sample about how to ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't tried with nested attributes, but you might want to look into [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for tracking changes.

Answer (score 0):

After several options (thank's Beerlington) with same above article I did I wanted:

Read this: [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html)

```
def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.assign_attributes(params[:customer])
    if @customer.valid?
      # If changued I revise the record in the model
      @customer = @customer.requires_log if @customer.changed?
      # and very useful: @customer.changes gives you an array con every changue
      @customer.save
    end
    # similar for addresses and phones but into a loop:
    # @customer.addresses.each do |address|   ...  end
    # I didn't put it because it is repetitive
  end
```

The important things in the procedure are:

1. To apply the assign_attributes instead save to track changues before save.
2. In this particular case apply valid? to track only correct changues.
3. Work with changues, then save, etc.